# Is it possible to use the modflow package RT3d in Python?

Tags: flopy

Is it possible to use the modflow package RT3d, or another chemical reaction packgae in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a python package that supports RT3D. But all the RT3D inputs are just text files, so you can make them yourself and make required MT3D data sets using flopy.

RT3D is old, and pretty much not used anymore. Newer codes to look at would PHT3D and PHTUSG. Neither of these has python packages that I am aware, but I think there are free GUIs for PHT3D.